# nextjs: image from external url not loaded

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-tsx

there is an Image tag in my nextJs code that it's source is a url from unsplash.com .
i set this settings in config file:

```
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [{ hostname: "images.unsplash.com" }],
      },
      experimental: {
        serverActions: true,
      },
}
```

but the image still not loaded. i restart the project and also use domain instead of remotePatterns but they are not solution.
i take a screen shot from developer tools of browser part network:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhNX9.png)

how to solve this problem to load image from external url in my project?
nextjs version:14

Comment: Error says it is a server error, please provide log from there (terminal or vercel or other).

Comment: Is it a typo? You should use domains not domain in next.config.

Comment: @Phaki `domains` is deprecated in favor of `remotePatterns`

Comment: @grekier error in terminal say: ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error. code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'